# JQuery/Ajax URL referencing 

Tags: javascript, ajax, url

`actually, problem solved. I made a mistake putting mysql_real_escape() for the post value, so it was accessing the file, but nothing passed to database. Thanks for the help`

I have a problem of getting the url within .ajax() to refer to the correct folder

In the root I have folders `/functions` and `/js`

My php page included a js file `/js/min/custom-ck.js`

Inside `custom-ck.js`, I have .ajax() to refer to php file named `updatebg.php` within `/functions` folder (`/functions/updatebg.php`)

```
 $.ajax({
        url : '/functions/updatebg.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'text',
        data : {
            'bg' : bg
        },
```

Can someone help me getting the absolute url right?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So... what's the actual issue here?  What happens when the ajax call is executed?  Are you getting an error message?  What have you tried already in attempts to resolve your issue?

Comment: It doesn't seem like accessing the php file.

Comment: Sorry, we'll need a little more than "doesn't access the file."  What *does* it do?

Comment: `updatebg.php` is supposed to store a link of picture in database, and other page will use that link as the background picture. It was working before, but I organized files in different folders, so the url got kinda confusing. I think it doesn't reference the file correctly.

Comment: actually, problem solved. I made a mistake putting mysql_real_escape() for the post value, so it was accessing the file, but nothing passed to database. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you use something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) or some other HTTP monitor to see what URL the ajax call is actually using?  When you use a relative URL, it's going to append that to the end of the base path for the original request.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer that explains what you found and how you solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still kinda new here. Just posted my answer in below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, problem solved. I made a mistake putting `mysql_real_escape()` for the post value, so it was accessing the file, but nothing passed to database. Thanks for the help

Comment: Accept your own answer, and remove the (SOLVED) from title. It isn't need on SO. :)